# Subsheaves of locally free sheaves on a rational curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, vector-bundles

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, $\mathcal{E}$ a locally free sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ and $\mathcal{L} \subset \mathcal{E}$ a subsheaf of rank $1$. By Grothendieck's theorem, we know that $\mathcal{E}$ (resp. $\mathcal{L}$) is of the form $\oplus_{i=1}^{\mathrm{rk}(\mathcal{E})} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_k}(a_i)$ (resp. $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_k}(a)$). Does there exist an injective morphism $i:\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{E}$ such that $\mathcal{L}$ maps to just one component $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_k}(a_j)$ of $\mathcal{E}$ i.e., $i$ factors through an injective morphism $i':\mathcal{L} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1_k}(a_j)$ for some $1 \le j \le \mathrm{rk}(\mathcal{E})$?

Comment: Are you changing the given inclusion of $\mathcal{L}\subset\mathcal{E}$ to some arbitrary inclusion $i$?

Comment: @Mohan: Yes. $i$ can be different from the "natural" inclusion.

Comment: Here is a hint then. One has a non-zero (and thus injective) homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(a)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(b)$ if and only if $a\leq b$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It is very helpful. Could you please elaborate on the proof of the statement (the iff condition for non-zero homomorphism) or suggest a reference.

Comment: I can tell you how it goes, but it is so basic, I think it might be better that you read it in some book (like say, Hartshorne).